# Migrating shelvesets and MyWork to a new domain user

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Our IT decided to migrate AD to a new domain. Now, those who did migrate their accounts, facing an issue - they've lost code reviews and shelvesets. They didn't really lost it. It is still accessible via "Find Shelvesets" and enter `olddomain\user`. But "My Work" is now disconnected. And even opening the "My Work" query and modifying a user name to the old user, still no success.

To clarify - only users being moved to new domain, not the TFS server

Did anyone have done something like this and any recommendations, workarounds?

Comment: Hi T.S.,Azure DevOps Server was formerly named Visual Studio Team Foundation Server (TFS). It's the same for TFS server, more details about this command, you could refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/command-line/tfsconfig-cmd?view=azure-devops-2019#identities Did you get a chance to implement the solution that jessehouwing suggested? Were you able to resolve?

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT if you think that the answer below covers my question I can go ahead and accept it. However, looks like in my case we will have to go through suffering because we're moving users to new domain in 1-by-1 manner. **PS:** well,  yea, I am using TFS from the time it was invented after VSS. I just have not used Azure

Comment: Hi  T.S.，yes jessehouwing is absolutely right. If you just want to migrate accounts across domains in Active Directory and keep the TFS sever reside in old domain .
You could use TFSConfig Identities command which changes the security identifier (SID) of users and groups in your deployment of TFS. And actually you are able to  do this one-off. For example, follow `TfsConfig identities /change /fromdomain:Contoso1 /todomain:ContosoPrime`  shows how to change the SIDs for all accounts in TFS from the Contoso1 domain to the SIDs for accounts that have matching names in the ContosoPrime domain.

Comment: However, in your case seems you already changed part of them. This make things a little complicate. Once a user account is present in TFS, it cannot be removed or have another account mapped to it. For example, if you are moving DomainA/UserA to DomainB/UserB, the Identities command would only work to migrate the user if DomainB/UserB is not already present in TFS. So 1-by-1 manner is a more safer way in your situation. Which could reduce the chance of an error encountered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They unfortunately did the domain move incorrectly. If done correctly, the data will carry over to the new user. Unfortunately there is no proper fix after messing this up as TFS now has 2 records with a unique identifier. These records can' be removed or merged.

You should be able to do the following in a script:

- create a workspace (tf vc workspace)
- map the project folder (tf vc map)
- get latest (tf vc get)
- query all shelvesets of your old user (tf vc shevesets)
- in a loop

  - Unshelve shelfset (tf vc unshelve)
  - Shelve a new one under your current user (tf vc shelve)
  - Undo pending changes (tf vc undo)

A number of these commands support a `/format:xml` argument, making it easy to call them in a PowerShell script and extracting the data for the next steps.

I don't think my-work will restore the associated work items and all. My Work has been removed from recent versions of Visual Studio, so you could use this as a good time to get used to that.

Other things that may have gone missing:

- "My Queries" under work items
- My Capacity
- Work item associations
- Pending changes in workspaces

The correct way to do TFS domain migrations is to suspend the server, do the account migration, then run `tfsconfig identities`:

```
 {Server install path}\Tools>TfsConfig.exe identities /change /fromdomain:old /todomain:new /account:old /toaccount:new
```

But this can only be done as long as TFS hasn't yet synced the new identity into the database. This may help future issues as they move new users over.

Comment: Thanks! I will talk to the person who is doing this. Lets see if this is not too late. Basically, you're saying that if the user is not yet converted to new domain, it is not too late to convert properly correct?

Comment: Another thing, you said `C:\Program Files\Azure DevOps Server 2019`. We have regular TFS, not Azure

Comment: The process in unchanged since 2005 :) but the exact location of the config tool varies from setup to setup and version to version.